# How can I remove the bottom line from a chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I've created a chart using Chart.js for Angular. There is a gray line at the bottom that I don't know how to remove.

[image]

This is my chart config:

```js
const gradientBackNone = this.canvas.nativeElement
  .getContext("2d")
  .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 180);
gradientBackNone.addColorStop(0, "rgba(130,139,216,.8)");
gradientBackNone.addColorStop(0.4, "rgba(130,139,216,.2)");
gradientBackNone.addColorStop(1, "rgba(130,139,216,0)");

this.lineChartOptions.layout.padding = {
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0
}
this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.display = false;
this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.padding = 0;
this.lineChartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].gridLines.color = 'transparent';
this.lineChartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.display = false;
this.lineChartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.padding = 0;
this.lineChartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.borderColor = 'transparent';
this.lineChartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.zeroLineColor = 'transparent';
this.lineChartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.display = false;
this.lineChartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.drawBorder = false;
this.lineChartColors = [{
  borderColor: "#828bd8",
  backgroundColor: gradientBackNone
}];
```

Do you know why that line is still there if I have hidden borderColor, zeroLineColor, display and drawBorder properties?

Thanks mates

Comment: Hello @Losina, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I've submitted an edit to your question that just tweaks the tone and presentation a bit--you'll usually get the best results with as concise and non-emotive language as possible, and I expanded your link so that it's very clear what someone clicking on it should expect. Good luck with your question!